# Какую технологию использовать для простой доски объявлений?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, angularjs, meteor

Добрый день
Возникла проблема с выбором технологии для написания простой доски объявлений (дипломное задание), в дальнейшем планируется приложение для iOS и Android. 
Есть хорошие знания по php (не хочу писать диплом на php) и приемлемые по js. Смотрел в сторону фреймворков на js, но затрудняюсь с выбором.
Посоветуйте что либо, буду рад любому совету

Comment: Предполагается создание очень простой доски объявления в которой фигурирует один вид товаров

Comment: Доска объявлений типа " покупаю/продаю" для одного типа товаров так?

Comment: Все верно, у Вас очень четкий и доступный ответ на мой вопрос, благодарю

Comment: вы не бойтесь писать коментарий прямо к ответу=) Если вам помог ответ, пометьте его как правильный (зеленая галка рядом с ответом ). Так будет проще понять, дали ли вам ответ на ваш вопрос и помог ли он вам.

Comment: `Смотрел в сторону фреймворков на js, но затрудняюсь с выбором.` - Все просто, найдите на github. Смотрите когда обновился в последний раз, как регулярно обновляется и какой рейтинг. Потом смотрите документацию всё ли есть что вам надо.  Потом ищете туториалы и примеры. Выбираете тот, у которого лучшая поддержка и комйюнити.

Comment: http://todomvc.com/ - здесь запилены несколкьо примеров простого приложения на популярных mvc фреймворках. Может помочь понять с чем придется иметь дело

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос достаточно "специфичный" т.к. у каждого есть свои "предпочтения", если так можно сказать =).

Я бы смотрел в сторону ангуляра1.x [тут](https://angularjs.org/) + bootstrap. Angular2 если только много времени есть покопаться. Полученное приложение будет достаточно хорошо переделываться под iOS/Android ( можно вообще сделать mobilefirst дизайн и тогда сразу будет тебе готовый вариант под все устройства).Ну и механизм двухстороннего databinding-а тебе определенно понравится.  Но это только с точки зрения быстроты и удобства ( ну и дизайна).

Можно и на просто html5+js+CSS3, но такие приложения чаще всего достаточно кривые и имеют множество проблем (Все зависит от размера приложения).

Как вариант ReactJS [тут](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)- он мэинстримовый и имеет много фишек (я сам только начинаю познавать азы, но если нужен какой-то тип листенера стримов и реалтайм обменом данных,  то реакт очень хорошо с этим работает).

"Забивать гвозди микроскопом конечно можно, но если выбирать между валенком и микроскопом, то определенно лучше отложить это занятие подальше " =)

Т.е. Все зависит от задачи - насколько "глубоко" вы собираетесь создавать доску объявлений, в каких направлениях и т.п. Немаловажный аспект еще в том, будете ли вы использовать back-end или же будете что-то лепить прямо на фронте.

**Важно**
Back-end все таки придется запилить,хотя бы самый простой. Для этой цели есть : WebAPI+EF+MSSQL, Node.js+MySQL и т.п.

**UPDATE**

Просто приложение доски объявлений обычно состоит из нескольких форм. Например сама доска, окно создания/редактирования тикета (может быть разделено на 2 формы), форма просмотра, форма подтверждения (опционально), админка (опционально), форма регистрации/логина. Всего где то ~20 функций и 6 вьюх. Для такого малого объема задач я бы не заморачивался сильно и сделал бы на js логику ( стучался бы через ajax за данными). Но для диплома и красоты прикрутить angular будет проще всего (особенно если ты с ним уже знаком- пару контроллеров, сервис для работы с реквестами к бд). С дизайном тоже самое - можно и просто HTML5/CSS3, но bootstrap меньше боли при создании внешнего вида(почти все уже готово за тебя) и адаптивный дизайн доступен "из коробки".

Comment: думаю без бекенда никак не обойтись данные объявлений надо где-то хранить и загружать

Comment: @JK_Action я полностью согласен т.к. тогда приложение выглядит "законченным". Но есть например breezeJS, которая логику по работе с бд переносит на фронт (хотя там все равно нужен посредник).

Comment: <holywar>Мой юный друг, не выбирай ангуляр пжлста</holywar>

Comment: @Утка ;) вы знаете толк мсье) Но я не пропагандирую за Ангуляр - просто это самый быстрый способ что-то сделать простое с использованием "красивых и громогласных слов" в дипломе типа фрэймворк, двухсторонний датабиндинг, watch и все такое =) Нативный JS конечно круче, но пилить долго (+ накосячить можно, что потом искать будешь ночами).

Comment: @alexoander, я из секты реакта. Мне не нравится ангуляр. Тем, что во-первых это какой-то свой особый мир, отдельный от остального js мира. Во-вторых, первый ангуляр неоправданно переусложнен на мой взгляд. Порог входа там относительно велик, так что для маленьких приложений он не оправдывается. На больших приложениях как я слышал приходится чрезмерно много бороться с фреймворком. Если нужен "монстр из коробки", куча готовых ui компонентов, и "spa одним кликом", то например extjs есть.

Comment: В общем субъективно "ангуляр фуфуфу", и я не единственный человек с таким впечатлением. Не, конечно можно и на ангуляре писать, многим он нравится, но начинать знакомство с js фреймворками с ангуляра - мне кажется это может сильно травмировать психику человека плохо знакомого с js.

Comment: @Утка не будем разворачивать холивар=) ты вроде этот тег закрыл, но все равно продолжил. Заметь - я дал человеку выбор а дальше - это уже его решение)

Comment: @alexoander, ну ок, я обоснвоал просто, больше не буду)

Comment: @Утка Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

В 2016/2017 для диплома будет прекрасно смотреться ReactJS

Comment: думаю для диплома будет прекрасно смотреться **нативный js**, так как продемонстрирует хорошие знания самого языка, а не его фреймворков...... Отсюда вытекает -> овладение любым фрейворком за короткий промежуток времени, так как есть четкое понимание что и как работает и откуда берется.

Comment: Согласен Vanilla JS отличный фреймворк. Но боюсь автор, как нормальный студент, забъёт на диплом 80% отведённого времени, а в оставшиеся 20% на чистом js может не успеть

Answer (score 0):

Так как лучшие знания в тебя по js то хорошим выбором будет https://www.meteor.com/ , это js full stack framework. И в будущем будет удобно разрабатывать API для iOS и Android приложений.